# Disable Space key on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a text box which the user shouldn't be allowed to write spaces in.

So far I have this code:

```
private void SearchCriteria_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.ToString() == "Space")
    {
        DelLast = SearchCriteria.Text;
        NeedsToDelete = true;
    }
}

private void SearchCriteria_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (NeedsToDelete == true)
    {
        SearchCriteria.Text = DelLast;
        NeedsToDelete = false;
    }
}
```

It works, but the cursor is being placed in front of the text. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in your OnKeyDown event and then set it again within the OnKeyUpEvent

```
private void SearchCriteria_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e
{
    if (e.Key.ToString() == "Space")
    {
        DelLast = SearchCriteria.Text;
        NeedsToDelete = true;
        _selectionStart = SearchCriteria.SelectionStart;
    }
}
private void SearchCriteria_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (NeedsToDelete == true)
    {
        SearchCriteria.Text = DelLast;
        SearchCriteria.SelectionStart = _selectionStart;
        NeedsToDelete = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    private void SearchCriteria_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NeedsToDelete == true)
        {
            SearchCriteria.Text = DelLast;
            NeedsToDelete = false;
            SearchCriteria.Select(SearchCriteria.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
```